# Hibernate not including new database information

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jsp

I am using `Hibernate 2` and using `MsSQL` as my database. I added a column into the database, and when I try to access it gives me following exception:

```
System.out.println((((Project)tempList.get(0)).getIsActive()));
```

It doesn't work. I always get `null`. I think that `getHibernateTemplate()` is creating a project and not including the active field.  I don't understand it!

```
public Project findProject(String projectId) throws Exception
{
    Project proj = null;
    String queryStr = "from Project p where p.projectId=?"; 
    Object[] questionMark = new Object[]{new String(projectId)};
    List tempList = getHibernateTemplate().find(queryStr, questionMark);
    if(tempList.size()>0)
    {
        proj = (Project)(tempList.get(0));
    }
    System.out.println((((Project) tempList.get(0)).getProjectId()));
    System.out.println((((Project)tempList.get(0)).getIsActive()));
    return proj; 
    //find why this does not include the active state!!
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Hibernate 2? That's really, really, really (embarrassingly) old. Hibernate 3.0 came out in 2005. I don't even have anything in the medicine cabinet that goes back that far.

Comment: did you add this column only to database? Where is the part, telling hibernate about the new column?